# Fields are in different language in view vs in new/edit/display form

Tags: 2010, column, language

I have very strange SharePoint 2010 behaviour.

Basically I have SharePoint site in 2 languages, default is English and there is German. So when I change my language to German then there is everything in German if English then English, BUT one problem.

The problem is following for example when I change to German, I go to the list all the column names are in German, BUT when I go to the new form or display form, to view an item, those fields are shown in English.

These Assigned To or other fields are well translated everywhere, in views, in list settings, everywhere, BUT if I want to Add new item, or edit item or display item, on these views it is then in English.

Did anyone had this kind of behaviour?

And what kind of resolution could be?

Comment: SharePoint 2010 stores the currently selected language in a cookie called `lcid`. The  forms are displayed using `IFrames`. Have you checked the value of the cookie in the `IFrame`?

Comment: I'll try to see, how i can check that

Comment: Can you assist where to check that cookie?

Comment: running `document.cookie` in the console will show you the cookies. In Chrome DeveloperTools -> Application -> Storage -> Cookies. For IE check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19941029/how-do-i-view-cookies-in-internet-explorer-11-using-developer-tools

Answer (score 0):

The solution is localization.
See [Understanding the Multilingual User Interface (MUI)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ff800886(v=office.14)) for an introduction.

Generally you could either deploy resources `*.resx` files and get the localization by having titles like `$Resources:myResource, myId` or you could uitlize [`SPField.Titleresource`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-server/ee552058(v%3Doffice.15)) on which you then can call [`SetValueForUICulture`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ee580461(v%3Doffice.14))

Comment: What you write is not appliably to my situation, because as I've described, the issue is a bit different. For example AssignedTo is a default field and it has translation by default with the installed language + if you see the general view it is translated, BUT when you try to edit item or create a new THERE it is in English although my language is set to German.

Comment: Oh, I see. Was the form modified i.e. using SharePoint designer?

Comment: no, it was not modified, default forms